# A URL could not be generated for this node because the branch it is contained in requires that a hostname is assigned

Tags: umbraco

I have installed Umbraco 5 and Configured a site. Then I have added a document type in the settings section. As soon as I add a page in the Content section it's shows the error "A URL could not be generated for this node because the branch it is contained in requires that a hostname is assigned". Any idea?

Comment: Where does the error show? CMS node tree? Cntent editor pane? When you try serving it on localhost? Other than that, this is actually off-topic, unless there is any programming involved on your part.

Comment: When I go to the Content Section and add new content by clicking the right click, and choose the new Document type and click on the Next button, it is showing this error.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have more than one root-level page.  Without adding a host name, you can only have one root-level page under the `Content` directory -- this represents the home page of your site, and all other pages should be added hierarchically below it.